# How to open a file using Runkit_Sandbox

Tags: php

I use the following code to open a file with Runkit_Sandbox:

```
<?php
$options = array(
  'open_basedir'=>'/var/www/html/test/',
  'allow_url_fopen'=>'true',
);
$sandbox = new Runkit_Sandbox($options);
$sandbox->ini_set('html_errors',true);

$sandbox->fopen('/var/www/html/test/data.txt', 'r');

?>
```

I already create the `data.txt` file in '/var/www/html/test/' directory with an appropriate permission. However, I still get this error:

```
Warning: Runkit_Sandbox::__call(): Unable to translate resource, or object variable to current context. in /var/www/html/test/write1.php on line 10
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know about RUNKIT, however something tells me you should change `'open_basedir'=>'/var/www/html/test',` to `'open_basedir'=>'/var/www/html/test/',` then `('/var/www/html/test/data.txt', 'r')` to `('data.txt', 'r')` try that, see if it makes it kick into gear.

Comment: I updated the question. Actually, I first wrote the script like in your comment above but it didn't work. Runkit needs absolute file path.

Comment: Ok. I'm unable to test your code. After trying sample code from PHP.net, am getting the following error `Fatal error: Class 'Runkit_Sandbox' not found in...` sorry I couldn't be of more help (*I tried*). (am on a hosted server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fopen()` returns a resource. Resources and objects cannot be exchanged between interpreters. What you basicly do is open the file inside the sandbox, and ask to return the file handle from the sandbox into your current context. This is not possible.

You can use eval():

```
$sandbox->eval('
  $f = fopen("/var/www/html/test/data.txt", "r");
  // ... rest of the code
');
```